# Zip file empty using maven assembly plugin in pom

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

my pom.xml but i have written something like

```
.......
..........
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-archive</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
..........
.......
```

My assembly.xml is

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>${project.version}</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/${create.stage.directory}</directory>
             <includes>
                <include>*.*</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/${create.release.directory}</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This creates an EMPTY foldername.zip in target!!NOT IN THE OUTPUT FOLDER LOCATION THAT I HAVE GIVEN.Is it always target? cant i override??
But in the given directory path I have 3 folders (in which some files) and readme.txt.I just tried giving *.txt inside include tag still I got empty zip folder. I initially guessed that my directory path and output directory path can be wrong.I directly hardcode still there is no luck.

Please help (This question is not duplicate but similar, and I have tried almost all stackoverflow questions related to this.they haven't solved anything)

Comment: What would you like to achieve? What is the `${create.stage.directory}` containing? Would you like to create a source package of the project ?

Answer (score 1):

For details see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet

Your descriptor is now configured like this:

- create a zip called `${project.artifactId}`
- from the directory `${project.basedir}/${create.stage.directory}` put all files with an extension (not directories, since it says `*.*`, not something like `**/*.*`  in the `${project.basedir}/${create.release.directory}` folder **inside** the zip.

Especially the last part is weird. Where in the zip should these files end? It should be a *relative* path to make it predictable.

Don't like the zip file to be created in target? Set the [outputDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#outputDirectory) in the plugin configuration, not in the assembly descriptor.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help.I have actually resolved empty zip problem with your help.
1)But still outputDIrectory problems persists.It is always going inside target directory since its default value is ${project.build.directory} .As you have seen I am giving different value but still unable to override.
2)Another problem is I want to zip what is inside a/b/c but after zipping the c contents and I open the zip folder, I see the a/b/x structure but I only want what's inside c. :( :'(

Comment: sorry point 1 above also got resolved.I typed it by mistake.But how do i only get the c but not a\b\c structure

Comment: change the `directory` of the fileset to `${project.basedir}/${create.stage.directory}/a/b`

Comment: Hi Thanks.I have the same .so in the output zip it creates with ${project.basedir}/${create.stage.directory}/a/b/c but I want what inside c.

${project.basedir}/${create.stage.directory} itself is project/a/b/c
I need whats inside c to be zipped inside the file name that I gave